# finding matches between a) all the files in a directory and b) a txt list of files not working with fnmatch - python

Tags: python, grep, fnmatch

So I've got the code below and when I run tests to spit out all the files in A1_dir and A2_list, all of the files are showing up, but when I try to get the fnmatch to work, I get no results.

For background in case its helpful: I am trying to comb through a directory of files and take an action (duplicate the file) only IF it matches a file name on the newoutput.txt list. I'm sure there's a better way to do all of this lol, so if you have that I'd love to hear it too!

```
import fnmatch
import os 

A1_dir = ('C:/users/alexd/kobe')

A2_list = open('C:/users/alexd/kobe/newoutput.txt')
Lines = A2_list.readlines()
A2_list.close()

for file in (os.listdir(A1_dir)):
    for line in Lines: 
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, line):
            print("got one:{file}")
```

Comment: Python `readline` and `readlines` returns the lines with a `\n` at the end. I'm assuming the files don't have a `\n` at the end. You'll need to write code to modify each element in `Lines` to remove the trailing `\n`. e.g. `Lines = [i.strip() for i in Lines]`

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `grep`?

Answer (score 1):

`readline` returns a single line and `readlines` returns all the lines as a list ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)). However, in both cases, the lines always have a trailing `\n` i.e. the newline character.

A simple fix here would be to change

```
Lines = A2_list.readlines()
```

to

```
Lines = [i.strip() for i in A2_list.readlines()]
```

Since you asked for a better way, you could take a look at set operations.
Since the lines are **exactly** what you want the file names to be (and not patterns), save A2_list as a set instead of a list.

Next, save all the files from `os.listdir` also as a set.

Finally, perform a [set intersection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)

```
import fnmatch
import os

with open('C:/users/alexd/kobe/newoutput.txt') as fp:
    myfiles = set(i.strip() for i in fp.readlines())

all_files = set(os.listdir('C:/users/alexd/kobe'))

for f in all_files.intersection(myfiles):
        print(f"got one:{f}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use fnmatch.fnmatch to compare 2 different filenames, fnmatch.fnmatch only accepts 2 parameters filename and pattern respectively.

As you can see in the official documentation:

[image: official documentation]

Possible Solution:

I don't think that you have to use any function to compare 2 strings. Both os.listdir() and .readlines() returns you lists of strings.